# Python list Azure Blobs by pattern

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

With the [Python Azure API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) I would like to query blobs by a pattern.

For example, get all report pdf's (with the [Unix style path name pattern expansion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)):

```
block_blob_service.list_blobs('mycontainer', '**/reports/*.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that.

From the server side filtering perspective, only thing you could do is `filter blobs by prefix` i.e. filter blobs where name starts with a particular value (e.g `reports/`).

All other kind of filtering needs to be done on the client side itself.

Comment: so this has more to do with the limitations of the [Blob Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2)?

Comment: this is very, very unfortunate considering if you happen to be processing via azure (ala function) they charge you for that compute instead of facilitating it for you. figures.